# Spring MVC html img tag with class attribute

Tags: html, spring

I want to add image to my `HTML`. I have got `imgPath` from controller. Here is the code:

```
<c:forEach var="listValue" items="${listValue}">
    <li><a href="#"> <img class="avatar" alt="Lucas" src="${listValue.imgPath}"> </a>                        
    <strong>Name:</strong><a href="#">listValue.displayName</a><br>
</c:forEach>
```

When I try run this code, I get an error like this.

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at line 24
```

So how can I use `img` tag with attribute in `foreach loop`.

```
src="${listValue.imgPath}">
```

And this is my stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

root cause

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'imgPath' not found on type test.tr.jira.Emp
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:268)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:221)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:355)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:95)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:936)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(home_jsp.java:179)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:131)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Pivotal tc Runtime 3.1.1.RELEASE/8.0.23.A.RELEASE logs.
```

Comment: I doubt that that is the full stack trace...

Comment: can you try with changing var name i.e. listValue - listVal

Comment: i added all @M.Deinum

Comment: i dont understand why i should do this ? @HarshalPatil

Comment: Well the exception is pretty clear... `PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'imgPath' not found on type test.tr.jira.Emp` there is no `getImgPath` method on the `Emp` class.

Comment: it's worked. thank you so much @M.Deinum